# Upload/Download images from my server to iOS app?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, web-services, image

I am working on a social networking app for iOS and have a mySQL Database and I have written a web service in php. I have everything working (create account/ loging in), but I am not sure how to Upload or Download images from the server.  When the user creates an account I create a folder on the server for that users images via

```
<?php
mkdir("members/$id", 0755);
?>
```

On the app side I am uploading an image like so

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/edit_profile.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley1.jpg"]);
[request setPostValue:imageData forKey:@"pic"];
[request setDelegate:self];
request startAsynchronous];
```

then on edit_profile.php

```
if (isset($_POST["pic"])){
    //Not sure what to do here
    //I've done this from a website before via:
    /*
    $newname = "image01.jpg";
    $place_file = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "members/$id/".$newname);
    $success_msg = "Image uploaded succcessfully!";
    */
}
```

Comment: I changed 'fileField' to 'pic' and I get the same result.

Comment: with     $place_file = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], "members/$id/".$newname) or die("FAILED to Upload");   I get "FAILED to Upload"

Comment: Ensure your form type is multi-part, ensure that $id is set, ensure that permission is correct. 755 is rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: $id is set, how do I make sure the form type is multi-part and permission is correct?

Comment: Ok I have made sure it is multi-Part still not sure on permission